# Need help on WCF Design

Tags: wcf

I have a project written in C++ COM+(Server Side) and VB6(Client Side). We have decided to redesign the project in WCF Architecture using C# language.
As a part of my learning, I have created a simple test Project in WCF which is below.
The idea is that when the WBWindowsService is started, it should create a TASWB object and then Run a Thread to Calculate the Weight. So when a client call the Getweight() method, it should be able to receive the weight calculated by the thread.
But when I tried, I am always getting 0 which is the initial value. So I think what i am missing is how to manage the objects in WCF.
Kindly Help. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Configuration.Install;

namespace TASWeighBridge
{
    public class WBWindowsService : ServiceBase
    {
        public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
        private TASWB obj;
        public WBWindowsService()
        {
            // Name the Windows Service
            ServiceName = "WBWindowsService";


        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new WBWindowsService());


        }

        // Start the Windows service.
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                serviceHost.Close();
            }

            obj = new TASWB();
            obj.RunThread();
            // Create a ServiceHost for the CalculatorService type and 
            // provide the base address.
            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TASWB));

            // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
            // listening for messages.
            serviceHost.Open();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                serviceHost.Close();
                serviceHost = null;
            }
        }
    }
}




using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Configuration.Install;


namespace TASWeighBridge
{
    // Define a service contract.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWeighBridge
    {
        [OperationContract]
        double Getweight();
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Threading;
namespace TASWeighBridge
{
    // Implement the ICalculator service contract in a service class.
    public class TASWB : IWeighBridge
    {
        private double weight = 0;

        public void RunThread()
        {
            Thread T1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CalcWeight));
            T1.Start();
            //T1.Join();
        }


        private void CalcWeight()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            weight = weight + 1;
        }
        public double Getweight()
        {
            return weight;
        }
    }
}

App.Config

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>    <services>
      <!-- This section is optional with the new configuration model
           introduced in .NET Framework 4. -->
      <service name="TASWeighBridge.TASWB"
               behaviorConfiguration="TASWBBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/TASWBService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- this endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost:8000/TASWBService  -->
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="TASWeighBridge.IWeighBridge" />
        <!-- the mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost:8000/TASWBService/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TASWBBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There is no need to do threading here for your sample. you simply expose the Operation contracts with the service contracts to the client and write your methods are normal in the WCF service. then from the client, you just create an instance of the ServiceClient or add reference to the service and call the method in question

Comment: Ahmed, in my real design threading is needed as it need to run as different process and its a multy threaded Service. As i mentioned earlier, i hv tried what u have mentioned but always getting 0 which is the initial value of varable weight. ☺